# IOS ANDROID mobile application delivery solution

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I work in a company and I would like to find out about the distribution of applications on google Play and Appstore basically I want to have an account for my company where I distribute all the applications while delegating the right to my developers to distribute the application via the same account but removing this right afterwards is it possible? and also if I have N applications in this account these developers if I give them access will they have access to other applications that do not concern them or is it possible to lock the other applications and only give them access has the desired application can I also have control over all these applications and give access rights to whoever I want on this account and restrict the rights I want and one last question how many applications can I broadcast on the same google play account and budget level what is the amount. I thank you

I just want an answer

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/. There is no limit to the number of apps a particular App Store account can publish.